# Ubuntu takes 7 minutes to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, snap, plymouth

this morning while booting my Ubuntu 20.04, it took more than 7 minutes:

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 6.728s (firmware) + 2min 6.556s (loader) + 18.334s (kernel) + 4min 55.330s (userspace) = 7min 26.950s 
graphical.target reached after 4min 51.146s in userspace
```

Sometimes, it happens for my system where it boots up that slow. Here is the result of:

```
systemd-analyze blame:\
2min 25.524s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
1min 25.990s systemd-journal-flush.service                                                            
1min 25.347s tor@default.service                                                                      
1min 16.195s upower.service                                                                           
  1min 422ms snapd.service                                                                            
     57.070s udisks2.service                                                                          
     37.890s dev-sda8.device                                                                          
     32.713s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
     20.485s apache2.service                                                                          
     18.973s networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
     18.200s dev-loop27.device                                                                        
     17.939s dev-loop24.device                                                                        
     17.630s phpsessionclean.service                                                                  
     16.869s dev-loop23.device                                                                        
     16.844s dev-loop15.device                                                                        
     16.330s dev-loop14.device                                                                        
     16.210s dev-loop18.device                                                                        
     16.180s dev-loop11.device                                                                        
     16.162s dev-loop21.device                                                                        
     16.004s dev-loop26.device                                                                        
     15.943s dev-loop22.device                                                                        
     15.939s dev-loop25.device                                                                        
     15.652s dev-loop12.device                                                                        
     15.624s dev-loop20.device                                                                        
     15.604s dev-loop17.device                                                                        
     15.547s dev-loop13.device                                                                        
     15.433s dev-loop7.device                                                                         
     15.368s dev-loop19.device                                                                        
     14.728s systemd-random-seed.service                                                              
     14.649s accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
     14.362s dev-loop0.device                                                                         
     14.009s dev-loop16.device                                                                        
     13.942s fwupd.service                                                                            
     13.763s dev-loop10.device                                                                        
     11.919s dev-loop4.device                                                                         
     11.908s polkit.service                                                                           
     11.754s dev-loop1.device                                                                         
     11.351s NetworkManager.service                                                                   
     11.309s dev-loop9.device                                                                         
     11.153s dev-loop8.device                                                                         
     10.945s dev-loop2.device                                                                         
     10.884s avahi-daemon.service                                                                     
     10.878s bluetooth.service                                                                        
     10.735s switcheroo-control.service                                                               
     10.734s dev-loop5.device                                                                         
     10.719s thermald.service                                                                         
     10.717s systemd-logind.service                                                                   
     10.702s wpa_supplicant.service                                                                   
     10.455s dev-loop6.device                                                                         
     10.376s dev-loop3.device                                                                         
     10.143s user@125.service                                                                         
      8.581s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                           
      8.334s gpu-manager.service                                                                      
      8.331s grub-common.service                                                                      
      7.101s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                                             
      6.306s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                                           
      5.839s snap-android\x2dstudio-100.mount                                                         
      5.733s systemd-udevd.service                                                                    
      5.712s snap-android\x2dstudio-99.mount                                                          
      5.707s snap-bitwarden-40.mount                                                                  
      5.703s bolt.service                                                                             
      5.158s teamviewerd.service                                                                      
      4.970s tlp.service                                                                              
      4.626s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9ec8f356\x2dc2e1\x2d4a3d\x2d835a\x2dc6ed3326ca8f.service
      4.365s snap-core-10583.mount                                                                    
      4.360s snap-core-10823.mount                                                                    
      4.105s apport.service                                                                           
      4.008s ModemManager.service                                                                     
      3.959s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                       
      3.843s apparmor.service                                                                         
      3.797s snap-core18-1944.mount                                                                   
      3.737s secureboot-db.service                                                                    
      3.654s gdm.service                                                                              
      3.155s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-32D7\x2d94B3.service                                    
      2.841s snap-core18-1988.mount                                                                   
      2.745s snapd.seeded.service                                                                     
      2.741s snap-core20-875.mount                                                                    
      2.717s snap-core20-904.mount                                                                    
      2.716s snap-discord-120.mount                                                                   
      2.711s systemd-resolved.service                                                                 
      2.699s snap-discord-121.mount                                                                   
      2.655s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount                                                  
      2.608s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount                                                   
      2.578s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount                                                   
      2.561s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1513.mount                                                  
      2.514s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount                                                  
      2.500s snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dultimate-266.mount                                              
      2.434s snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dultimate-269.mount                                              
      2.397s snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d14\x2dcore18-4.mount                           
      2.392s snap-netbeans-35.mount                                                                   
      2.386s snap-netbeans-41.mount                                                                   
      2.380s snap-postman-132.mount                                                                   
      2.375s snap-postman-133.mount                                                                   
      2.296s snap-snap\x2dstore-498.mount                                                             
      1.883s e2scrub_reap.service                                                                     
      1.756s rtkit-daemon.service                                                                     
      1.747s rsyslog.service                                                                          
      1.697s systemd-sysctl.service                                                                   
      1.679s home.mount                                                                               
      1.543s systemd-remount-fs.service                                                               
      1.440s snapd.apparmor.service                                                                   
      1.237s colord.service                                                                           
      1.159s plymouth-read-write.service                                                              
      1.064s user@1000.service                                                                        
       918ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                                            
       887ms vboxweb.service                                                                          
       617ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                                      
       572ms systemd-journald.service                                                                 
       545ms systemd-sysusers.service                                                                 
       539ms keyboard-setup.service                                                                   
       465ms snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount                                                             
       461ms virtualbox.service                                                                       
       442ms plymouth-start.service                                                                   
       406ms pppd-dns.service                                                                         
       401ms setvtrgb.service                                                                         
       335ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                             
       291ms modprobe@drm.service                                                                     
       270ms systemd-modules-load.service                                                             
       260ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                
       239ms snap-snapd-11036.mount                                                                   
       198ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                                      
       196ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                                         
       193ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                                   
       191ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                                 
       186ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                                
       170ms snap-snapd-10707.mount                                                                   
       148ms user-runtime-dir@125.service                                                             
       145ms ufw.service                                                                              
       131ms snap-webstorm-189.mount                                                                  
        90ms console-setup.service                                                                    
        88ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                                            
        81ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b2c295e5\x2deb17\x2d49a4\x2d95f3\x2d4322f4b6d092.swap                
        78ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                                              
        73ms kerneloops.service                                                                       
        68ms boot-efi.mount                                                                           
        35ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                                     
        21ms openvpn.service                                                                          
        18ms tor.service                                                                              
         8ms nordvpnd.socket                                                                          
         6ms alsa-restore.service                                                                     
         5ms snapd.socket                                                                             
         5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                                            
         4ms sys-kernel-config.mount
```

result of critical chain

```
systemd-analyze critical-chaine
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @4min 51.146s
└─multi-user.target @4min 40.998s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @3min 3.716s +2.745s
    └─snapd.service @2min 3.288s +1min 422ms
      └─basic.target @2min 2.927s
        └─sockets.target @2min 2.927s
          └─snapd.socket @2min 2.919s +5ms
            └─sysinit.target @2min 2.696s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @2min 2.435s +260ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1min 53.662s +8.581s
                  └─systemd-journal-flush.service @27.668s +1min 25.990s
                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @26.117s +1.543s
                      └─systemd-journald.socket @25.929s
                        └─system.slice @25.915s
                          └─-.slice @25.915s
```

I suspect snap behind this. Now my machine is very slow, opening apps took several time also. I've found also some mounted partition that never showed on my file explorer (efi, Filesystem, home):
(https://postimg.cc/YvzjWZW9)

And also, while shutting down yesterday my machine, it also took several minutes. I don't understand this behavior, I didn't install/uninstall something, sometimes it works perfectly and fast, but sometimes I have this issue.

Here is my configuration:

- I5 7200U
- 8 GO DDR4
- HDD
- Intel Graphics + Geforce 920MX (I'm using Intel)
  My system is a dual-boot with Windows 10.

Any ideas ? Thank you.

*EDIT*:
I've just found that my other partitions (C(Windows), D, E) are not visible on 'Other locations'.

Comment: Have you checked that your root drive hasn't got a hardware fault..  ?

IO Errors cause retries which are normally logged but it can make things very very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` file and the "quiet splash" line should be "" afterwards, then the `sudo update-grub` command is run. Now you will get to see your boot messages and where it is failing in each step of the boot process. You will certainly get to see the delays in each step with a boot that long. If you see i/o errors as has been mentioned the drive prepares to die on you. Once sorted edit again to replace the edited out settings then update to get back the graphic screen.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I just want to precise that after restarting my machine, everything was OK. the time went down till 1mn something.. But after reading your comment, I checked the health of my hardrive using Gnome disk utility, I am bit concerned about the value of "Read Error Rate" which is: 8958553. Also, it says my Disk is OK with 888 bad sectors. What does it mean ?

Comment: It means it gets ready to die on you unfortunately, you can do the bad blocks idea on it but when I did it couple weeks ago it failed  within short period of time and so did the drive. This does not mean yours will fail but I would make certain all important information is backed up from the machine in case a re-install is needed on new drive.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also experienced worse performances on my Windows partition and I understand now why. Thank you for help, I have to backup my data before it will be late. Just one more last question, I've just did another test, but It fails with a message "Last self-test failed (read)"

Comment: It means get as much off of it as you can, it goes soon I fear.

Comment: Got it, thank you! :)